# How to open a External browser in Eclipse Editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin

How to open an External browser like Safari from open option with in Eclipse plugin programmaticly?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you elaborate a little? What do you want to open?

Comment: I want to open chrome browser same like we open Web Browser through HTML File --->open with--Chrome

Comment: OK, so you want to connect the file name of the `IEditorInput` you get from the navigator with the input of the browser. Not difficult at all. There are a number of things though you have to look at, the most important being setting the correct base location of the web page so the browser can retrieve other parts of the page such as CSS and JS. You can have more problems if you want to support linked files as well... :-)

Comment: Ok,It takes SWT.NONE for default browser .What API Or any other thing we have to pass to open Safari browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try {
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getBrowserSupport().getExternalBrowser().openURL(new URL("http://stackoverflow.com"));
} catch (PartInitException | MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will open the external browser.

Comment: Is there any way to open url in external browser of specific type. Like we do in open with Firefox or IE etc?