# Is it possible to redirect to browser URL on splash image click?

Tags: java, splash-screen, eclipse-pde

I use PDE. My tool has a splash image located in `splash.bmp`. In the `build.properties` I include the image into `bin.includes` (`bin.includes = splash.bmp`). In the `app.product` file I have the following code:

```
   <splash startupProgressRect="5,275,445,15" />
   <launcher name="app">
      <linux icon="/icons/running.xpm"/>
      <win useIco="false">
         <bmp/>
      </win>
   </launcher>
```

My question is the following: Is it possible to add links in the splash image? I mean, once the app is loading, it possible to click on specific section in the splash and it will open the browser with a link?

Using Java8 and Eclipse Photon if that matters. Is it even possible? Maybe a hint?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a custom **splash handler**:

The native launcher of Eclipse creates the window for the splash screen and draws the configured bitmap on it. Any additional functionality (e.g. the progress bar) is implemented in Java. Since Eclipse 3.3. this implementation can be customized through the extension point  [org.eclipse.ui.splashHandler](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_splashHandlers.html&resultof%3D%2522%2573%2570%256c%2561%2573%2568%2522%2520).

The default implementation is `org.eclipse.ui.internal.splash.EclipseSplashHandler` ([source](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/Eclipse%20UI/org/eclipse/ui/internal/splash/EclipseSplashHandler.java)). You can either extend your custom implementation from this or any sub class of it or you can implement your own custom handler from scratch.

The `init` method of your custom handler implementation is called with a `Shell` that represents the splash window. You can easily add additional controls to the splash screen, including a `Hyperlink` control or a `Label` with a mouse listener.

Latest Eclipse PDE (not tested with Photon) can even generate an interactive splash example. Double click on the MAINFEST.MF of your main UI plugin -> Extensions -> Add.. -> select `org.eclipse.ui.splashHandler` -> Select `Splash Handler` template at the bottom -> Next -> Select `Interactive - A simulated log-in session` -> ensure that `Add a default splash screen to this plug-in` is checked.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  I have created a class that extends `EclipseSplashHandler` and implemented `init`. But how exactly I add a URL redirection in the image?

Comment: you can add a mouse listener to the shell and open an URL based on the coordinates of the mouse event or you could place a hyperlink control over the image (not sure whether the hyperlink control supports transparent background on all operating systems). If you use a mouse listener you can open the URL in the browser as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8227384/13510562

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks. There is a time gap between showing the splash and adding the urls/version to the splash using the Handler. Do you know how to remove this awkward time gap?

Comment: i think best would to use latest eclipse and generate the Interactive log-in example as described in my answer. the generated code shows a splash with two login controls without any delay. you could use this code as base and check how the controls are added. an alernative solution would be to add the text of the link to your splash bitmap and use a mouse listener.

Comment: @vesii In addition to use the latest Eclipse, use also the latest Java to run your application (the OpenJ9 can reduce the start-up time by 30%) and [make sure, your plugins do not cause the delay](https://alblue.bandlem.com/2020/07/why-servicecaller-is-better.html). I have an RCP application that starts in less than 3 seconds (based on Eclipse 4.18 with Java 15), just to give you an example of what is possible.